# IOException on watermarking video on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to programmatically watermark a video in Android using WritingMinds' Ffmpeg library from Github :

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

I did all they said in their documentation and imported the library in Android Studio.

Still, it gives me an IOExeption with "No such file or directory".

CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn;
Context context;

String str;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

context = this;

str = "ffmpeg -i /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/video.avi -i /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/logo.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:main_h overlay_h-10' /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/watermarked.avi";

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

doFfmpeg(str.split(" "));

    }
  });
 }
}

public void doFfmpeg(String[] loc){

FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);

try {
// to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
ffmpeg.execute(loc, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

@Override
public void onStart() {
}

@Override
public void onProgress(String message) {
}

@Override
public void onFailure(String message) {
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(String message) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
  }
 });
} catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
// Handle if FFmpeg is already running
} catch (Exception e){

}

 }
}
```

LOGS

```
691 5092-5311/com.app.watermark.watermark E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [Ljava.lang.String;@338dbc60
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/data/com.app.watermark.watermark/files/ffmpeg, -i, /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/video.avi, -i, /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/logo.png, -filter_complex, 'overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10', /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/watermarked.avi] Working Directory: null Environment: null
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128)
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10)
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38)
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173) 
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128) 
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10) 
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38)
at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with a slightly different approach.

I used Ffmpeg4Android as told on WarZone :

http://androidwarzone.blogspot.ro/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

Here it tells you how you should configure Ffmpeg4Android :

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FWMAT3FbCXlW_91d6Ek_UCD_CtYJWxYaDVY2hE6Onig/edit

The downside is that momentarily if you want to import their project, you have to manually include it in your project and this will result in an enormous apk.

Although for the moment, it works fine and does it's job.